# Using the hub gem, how can I open a pull request with both title and body?

Tags: ruby, github

`hub pull-request -m "Some message"` opens a pull request with a title but no body.

Using `-m "Some title\n\nSome body"` does not help; the `"\n\n"` is simply displayed in the title.

How can I open a pull request with both title and body from the command line using the hub gem?

Answer (score 1):

## Use `-F -` and STDIN

For example:

```
echo "Some Title\n\nSome body" | hub pull-request -F -
```